# Vim Crashing with Python 3: "Caught deadly signal ABRT glibc detected..."

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim

Something is very wrong with my vim to python 3 setup where when I type `:py3 import sys; print(sys.version)` I just get a complete crash with something along the lines of:

```
Vim: Caught deadly signal ABRT...
*** glibc detected *** /usr/local/bin/vim: 
corrupted double-linked list: 0x00000000015f9a50 ***.
```

I have a very functioning Anaconda python install with the below `:ver`. I have no clue how to begin trying to figuring out what the issue is:

```
:ver

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 10 2015 12:03:17)
Included patches: 1-891
Compiled by root@ip-10-239-197-136
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +clientserver    +cscope          +emacs_tags      +folding         +keymap          +menu            +mouse_netterm   +netbeans_intg   +python3         -sniff           -tcl             +virtualedit     +writebackup
+arabic          +clipboard       +cursorbind      +eval            -footer          +langmap         +mksession       +mouse_sgr       +path_extra      +quickfix        +startuptime     +terminfo        +visual          +X11
+autocmd         +cmdline_compl   +cursorshape     +ex_extra        +fork()          +libcall         +modify_fname    -mouse_sysmouse  -perl            +reltime         +statusline      +termresponse    +visualextra     +xfontset
-balloon_eval    +cmdline_hist    +dialog_con      +extra_search    +gettext         +linebreak       +mouse           +mouse_urxvt     +persistent_undo +rightleft       -sun_workshop    +textobjects     +viminfo         -xim
-browse          +cmdline_info    +diff            +farsi           -hangul_input    +lispindent      -mouseshape      +mouse_xterm     +postscript      -ruby            +syntax          +title           +vreplace        +xsmp_interact
++builtin_terms  +comments        +digraphs        +file_in_path    +iconv           +listcmds        +mouse_dec       +multi_byte      +printer         +scrollbind      +tag_binary      -toolbar         +wildignore      +xterm_clipboard
+byte_offset     +conceal         -dnd             +find_in_path    +insert_expand   +localmap        -mouse_gpm       +multi_lang      +profile         +signs           +tag_old_static  +user_commands   +wildmenu        -xterm_save
+cindent         +cryptv          -ebcdic          +float           +jumplist        -lua             -mouse_jsbterm   -mzscheme        -python          +smartindent     -tag_any_white   +vertsplit       +windows         -xpm
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim    -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux      -L/ebs/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m -lpython3.4m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
```

Comment: I have the same problem with a selfcompiled vim for python 3 :/

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: I started just compiling my own python instead of using Anaconda and stopped encountering this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system you are using?, if it is a debian based linux distribution  intall the following package through terminal, it may work

```
sudo apt install vim-gtk
```

For other distros the package manager may be different but try to install the package vim-gtk and see if it fixes the problem